# Problem with Postgresql, LIKE gives double results

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working with Postgresql and I am facing a problem.

I have two tables "question" and "question_detail" in which there are codes. In "question_detail" are the codes including subcode so e.g. `TB01Q07`, `TB01Q07a`, `TB01Q08_SQ002`. Now I wanted to use the command `LIKE` to see if the table "question" also contains these records. But in "question.code" there are only codes without the following underscore. This is a table that was given to me, I find this somehow very stupid.

The problem is that when I search with `LIKE` the value `TB01Q07a` is listed twice. This is also understandable to me, since searching for `TB01Q07%` also returns the value `TB01Q07a`.

Does anyone know of a way to search only for `TB01Q07a` without it resulting in `TB01Q07%` as `TB01Q07a`?

**Command**

```
SELECT qd.code, qd.label, q.type
FROM public.question q, 
     public.question_detail qd
where CASE 
         WHEN qd.code = q.code THEN qd.code = q.code 
         ELSE qd.code like CONCAT(q.code,'%') 
      END;
```

**question**

````
| code     | type    |
| ---------|-------- |
| TB01Q07  | comment |
| TB01Q07a | comment |
| TB01Q08  | option  |

**question_detail**

```none
| code           | label |
| -------------- | ------|
| TB01Q07        | AB01 |
| TB01Q07a       | AB02 |
| TB01Q08_SQL002 | AB03 |
````

I ran the SQL and wanted the `TB01Q07a` value to appear only once and not be listed twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`like('TB01Q07%')` matches both TB01Q07 and TB01Q07a, so you get two rows for `TB01Q07` and one row for `TB01Q07a`.

You need to be more precise and include the underscore. Also make sure it's escaped, `_` means any one character in a like.

There is no need for a case, use `or`. Avoid using multiple `from` statements, use an explicit join with an explicit `on`. This is clearer and gives you more control over the join.

```
select qd.*, q.*
from public.question q
join public.question_detail qd
  on qd.code = q.code OR qd.code like q.code || '\_%'
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/thvwWaLm).

---

Note: this problem doesn't exist if you use [foreign keys](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_foreign_key.asp). Assign unique IDs to `question` and reference them in `question_detail`. This is faster, shields you from changes to the question code, and ensures the referred to question exists.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much! Yes in the future I will create my own database with primary keys and foreign keys. This database only needs to be used a little, then it will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution with distinct on.

```
SELECT distinct on (qd.code) q.id_question,qd.code, q.question, q.question_type
FROM public.question q, public.question_detail qd
where qd.code like CONCAT(q.code,'%');
```